# If $\text{cl(conv}(B))=A$, prove that $\text{ext}(A)\subset \text{cl}(B)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

If $A$ is a non-empty, compact and convex set in a finite dimension space, $B\subset A$ and $\text{cl(conv}(B))=A$. $\text{ext}(A)$ denotes the set of [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of $A$. Prove that $\text{ext}(A)\subset \text{cl}(B)$.

Suppose $a\in\text{ext}(A)$ is not in $\text{cl}(B)$. When $B$ is convex from Hyperplane separation theorem we derive $\text{cl(conv}(B))\neq A$. When $B$ is concave, there is a supporting hyperplane at $a$ and $A$ is in one side of the plane, then how to derive contradition?

Comment: Don't know if it helps but wlog (replacing B by cl(B)), B is compact and A=conv(B). So what you want to prove is: (in finite dimension) if B is compact then ext(conv(B))$\subset$B.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why B can be replaced by cl(B)? In other words, does cl(conv(B))=cl(conv(cl(B)))?

Comment: @AnneBauval This is an example that cl and conv can't exchange:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229781

Comment: Yes, cl(conv(B))=cl(conv(cl(B))) (which your previous comment does not contradict) and (since cl(B) is compact) conv(cl(B)) is compact.

Comment: This (together with my 1st comment) answers your question: [Extreme Points of a Convex Hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289850/extreme-points-of-a-convex-hull)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks!